# Contextually modify views output?

Tags: 7, theming

On the front page, i'd like the views to output taxonomy differently than i would on a term page.

I know i could modify output using a tpl file indicated by devel_themer; but i'm not certain how one would contextually change it.

How would i go about doing so with a preprocess function?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just get the current page with request_uri() and then use some logic to style a view on the home page differently.

Or just create a second view and use the front module to show that view on the home page.